# Main app component not able to get params

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a scenario where the first segment in the url will be a unique identifier. That unique identifier will be used in main routes and in the child routes as well.

Here is how i have defined my routes config

```
export const routes:RouterConfig = [{
    path: ':academy_url',
    children: [
        {path: '', component: CoursesComponent},
        {path: 'courses',
            children: [
                {path: '', component: CoursesComponent}
            ]
        }
    }
];
```

`:academy_url` is the param i plan on using in the child components. I can access this param in the child components (`CoursesComponent` for example), but i do not have for some reason access to it in the main `app` component.

The params array is empty in the main component when i try observables as well as snapshot.How do i access this param in app component? Right now i have a workaround which depends on a service emitting the param value from child components, but that is very inconvenient as this happens every time a component loads or page refreshed.

I need a more direct approach and i feel that it's either a bug or maybe the main app component is not supposed to have access to entry level params?

Also, i tried to create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TBBwBH7tMjU1GZUmz46e) but i'm not sure how i make it work in there as it gives me undefined route error for it's plunker url key.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @SteveSanders No. I wasn't. I had to use events to overcome this issue.